# How do you uninstall the Scala Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, scala

I tried to install the Eclipse plugin advertised in the Scala advertised at http://www.scala-lang.org/node/94.

I installed it onto my version of the SpringSource Tool Suite 2.2.1 thinking everything would be fine. 
I'm still using Mac OS 10.4, and thus have not upgraded to Java 6. Lo, and behold, I was wrong. I can't even restart STS anymore after adding the scala plugin. So I'd like to remove it from the config files so that Eclipse doesn't try to load it anymore. I've removed anything matching scala from artifacts.xml and config.ini. I've also removed the scala jars from the plugins directory. Still no luck.

Can any of you suggest anything further to remove the Scala plugin from Eclipse?

Answer (score 19):

In Eclipse 3.5.1, go to Help->About Eclipse, then press 'Installation Details'. In the tab 'Installed Software' you can remove a feature, in the tab 'Installation History' you can revert to a previous configuration. Since you manually removed pieces, it may be too late to fix things.

You can also check the features directory and start Eclipse with the -clean option to ensure that the OSGi bundle cache is cleared.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't even get get Eclipse started to see the menus. :(

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with Eclipse not even starting for me anymore. What I did was to remove everything related to the Scala IDE from both the `plugins` and the `features` directories and start Eclipse with the `-clean` parameter:

```
./eclipse -clean
```

Comment: This sounds closer. i'll try it tonight.

Comment: If that does not work, manually delete the corresponding folders and jars in `eclipse/plugins` and `ecliplse/features`. And then start eclipse with the `-clean` option